# Nested route under id

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to nest a route using react-router v6 this way?

```
<Parent>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/items/:itemId" element={<ItemPage />} />
  </Routes>
</Parent>
```

```
<ItemPage>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="info" element={<ItemInfo />} />
    <Route path="settings" element={<ItemSettings />} />
  </Routes>

  <Sidebar />
</ItemPage>
```

So I could visit `/items/123/settings`? I am looking for indeed this way to work with router, so on separate `ItemPage` component layout would depend on child-route, keeping `Sidebar` on the side, but changing content according to info/settings "tab" selected.
Everywhere else in my app this way works, but for some reason it doesn't work with nested routes under `:id`.

This [doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#defining-routes) does show an example for kinda nested route, but it's not a nested one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the routes in the parent `Routes` component need to append the `*` wildcard matcher to the route so nested routes can also be matched. Nested `Routes` components build relative routes.

See [How do I nest routes deep in the tree?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree)

Example:

```
<Parent>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/items/:itemId/*" element={<ItemPage />} />
  </Routes>
</Parent>
```

...

```
<ItemPage>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="info" element={<ItemInfo />} />         // "/items/:itemId/info"
    <Route path="settings" element={<ItemSettings />} /> // "/items/:itemId/settings"
  </Routes>

  <Sidebar />
</ItemPage>
```